# Verification of ruby-generated RSA SHA256 signature fails in C#

Tags: c#, ruby, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I have the following code in ruby and C# to generate and verify RSA signature.

**Ruby**

Keys generation (in PEM format)

```
keys = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new 512
private_key = key.to_pem
public_key = key.public_key.to_pem
```

I store these keys in environment variables `ENV["PRIVATE_KEY"]` and `ENV["PUBLIC_KEY"]`

Generate signature

```
def generate_signature(token)
  sign_hash = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new
  priv = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(ENV["PRIVATE_KEY"])
  signature = Base64.urlsafe_encode64(priv.sign(sign_hash, token))
  signature.gsub!(/\n/, '')
end
```

Verify signature

```
def verify_signature(signature, token)
  verify_hash = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.new
  pub = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(ENV["PUBLIC_KEY"])
  pub.verify(verify_hash, Base64.urlsafe_decode64(signature), token)
end
```

given these methods, the following code returns **true**, so verification is **succesful**.

```
signature = generate_signature("string")
puts verify_signature(signature, "string")
```

**C#**

In C# I don't need to generate keys, I just need to verify signature, generated previously in ruby. Since `System.Security.Cryptography` doesn't work with PEM keys out of the box, I converted PEM key to XML format (using [online converter](https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter))

Here is verification code, which returns **false**, so verification is **unsuccesfull**.

```
public const string publicKey = @"Public key in XML format";
public static bool Verify(string nonce, string signature)
{
     RSACryptoServiceProvider RSAVerifier = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
     RSAVerifier.FromXmlString(publicKey);
     signature = Base64Decode(signature);
     byte[] SignatureBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(signature);
     byte[] VerifyFileData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nonce);

     bool isValidSignature = RSAVerifier.VerifyData(VerifyFileData, CryptoConfig.MapNameToOID("SHA256"), SignatureBytes);
     return isValidSignature;
 }
```

Where Base64Decode is my custom method to replicate Base64.urlsafe_decode64 in ruby

```
public static string Base64Decode(string base64EncodedData)
{
     byte[] base64EncodedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64EncodedData.Replace('-', '+').Replace('_', '/'));
     return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(base64EncodedBytes);
 }
```

Comment: "Where Base64Decode is my custom method to replicate Base64.urlsafe_decode64 in ruby " How come your base 64 decoder returns a string instead of bytes? Have you Unit-tested your base 64 decoder? Don't reuse your variables like this: `signature = Base64Decode(signature);`

Comment: OMG!! It works, after returned bytes from Base64Decode Thanks